# How can I mount my phone and my battery pack to my bike?

Tags: smartphone-mount

On long bike rides, my phone dies often. Is there any way I can mount my phone, a galaxy s5, and my battery pack, pictured, to my bike? I'd say that mounting to the handlebars would be ideal, but I'm open to suggestions.

[image]

Battery pack is a "Fremo P130"

Comment: A quick google search for "bicycle phone mounts" would answer your question on how to mount the phone, and "bicycle phone chargers" would give you different battery packs for your phone. Some will have both together.

Comment: @Batman I created this question at the request of criggie.

Comment: I'm sure criggie is more than capable of asking his own questions. I'm voting to close as product rec -- there are a ton of smart phone handlebar/stem mounts and phone chargers for bicycles on the market (check your bike shop or just use the search terms I stated in the last comment), and quite a few related questions in the side bar.

Comment: If you really want to use that particular battery pack, I'd just put it in a frame bag, or velcro/tape it on or something. The search terms before and "bicycle phone battery pack" or similar will give you battery packs which come with mounting hardware for a bicycle.

Comment: @Batman you misunderstand. He didn't say he wasn't capable, all in all, that doesn't even begin to make sense, but suggested that I propose my question to him as an actual question, so that other users can find it.

Comment: I also use a USB-powered bike headlight and want a battery pack conveniently in range when I need it, and out the way when I don't.  Currently I stash the battery in the rear seat pack and have a 3 foot USB cable running from there up the frame to the handlebars.  My setup works OK, but is not necessarily optimal.  Always looking for better options!

Comment: @Developer63 that's pretty smart. Do you just run the cable along the top tube?

Comment: It's a 10-year old Trek 7500FX sport hybrid, and the brake & shift cables are somewhat exposed on the top tube, so yes, I just tuck the USB cable under those on the top tube. Zip ties or twist ties would work but in my scenario I don't wind up needing them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a phone and a gopro, both of which have somewhat small batteries.

So to power them I use a USB battery which has two USB ports, one for each.  Its a little heavy but I'd rather lug that around than have my camera go flat in 90 minutes.

9 Ah battery
[image: 9000 mAh battery]

2.5 Ah battery
[image: 2500 mAh battery]

USB connectors are friction fit, which is fine at home on a desk but is not overly secure in the bumpy outside world.  So I use quite short USB cables to do the connection, and lay the phone on top of the battery inside a top-tube holder like this:

[image: top tube bag]

Some people ride wearing cycling tops, which generally have a couple of big pockets in the small of the back, so you could put a phone and a battery in there on a short lead and ignore it for the ride.

There are also USB power generating hubs, but they're pretty pricey.

Answer (score 6):

How about a top tube bag?

I've had a couple of handlebar mounts and they haven't lasted long in crowded bike sheds. Even mounted quite centrally they're vulnerable to knocks and aren't very strong.

A top tube bag with a clear lid works better for me. Do be sure to get one big enough though.  It will take the battery pack as well and should do a decent job of keeping everything dry (even if you have a waterproof phone you probably want to keep water out of the charging socket).

Comment: I use a top tube bag with a clear lid that I can use the phone through, and it holds my Nexus 6, a 20000 mAh battery, and some random bike tools quite well. It's lasted about 4000 miles so far.

Comment: I'm actually back on a handlebar mount most of the time (waterproof phone) because sun glare on the plastic cover meant I had to turn the screen brightness up all the way, and even then sometimes I couldn't read it

Answer (score 1):

This one looks like it will do the job for you, if you are willing to buy a new powerbank: https://r2-bike.com/TOPEAK-Smartphone-Mount-with-Powerpack

Answer (score 1):

I find that [Finn](http://getfinn.com/) (and other silicone clones) is really great.
[image]
Very safe, also easy to use on bikes other than yours.
I wouldn't use it with a too-large/too-thin smartphone though.
Useless with rain.

For the charger, either use a bike bag, or get a long roll of Velcro™, and then you can easily attach anything to the bike. Put some old tube (or any other elastic material) between the charger and the bike metal parts, to minimize vibration.

Comment: What stops the whole thing rotating around the bar?

Comment: @Criggie Friction: the silicone strings are also pulling the loop tight. Never has issue with rotation on surfaces of various materials (chromed steel, anodized aluminium).

Answer (score -3):

Stick your phone in your back pocket. Why would you want to ride round with it mounted on your bars? Better concentrating on bike riding than phone using.

Comment: Charging my phone in my pocket is a recipe for a destroyed micro usb port.

Comment: @Hellreaver its worked for me by using a short USB cable (10 cm), putting the oblong USB battery beside the phone in my middle back pocket, and having the cable point upward out of both.